# Qt creator "Undefined reference" to external C library

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I've read all other answers and try to follow but still got the error.
I use Qt 4.8.6 and QT creator 3.5.1. I include libproj in the .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/Qt/include/libproj-4.4
LIBS += -LC:/Qt/lib -lproj
```

The libproj.a is available in the specified dir, and src code is also available.
The header file is included in Projection.h:

```
extern "C" {
    #include <proj_api.h>
}
```

The function "pj_free" is called in Projection_libproj.cpp

Then I got the error:

```
C:\Users\ngu\Documents\jan-mayen\JanMaven\src\map\Projection_libproj.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `pj_free'
```

Comment: Try using this one `LIBS += C:/Qt/lib/libproj.a` instead of the above one (set the right path if I've used the wrong one).

Comment: Thanks. But it does not work

Comment: `LIBS += -LC:/Qt/lib -lproj` - are you sure you spelled the name right ? You say the library is `libproj.a`. Try `LIBS += -LC:/Qt/lib -llibproj`